# Optimizing a Dynamic 7-Day Cohort Firebase BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, http-status-code-400

I wrote the following query below against our mobile app's data. Due to a high user-base, I am getting a 400 request error `"Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory"` when I add the `ORDER BY` at the bottom.

Question: Is there anything that I can do to optimize the query, but still retain the `ORDER BY` at the bottom?

I already added in the firebase's demo data-set, but I think their data-set is just too small to have a problem (compared to my data-set which is 5-10 million records big).

```
SELECT 
  f.user_pseudo_id,
  f.event_timestamp, 
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(f.event_timestamp)) as event_timestamp_date,
  f.event_name,
  f.user_first_touch_timestamp,
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(f.user_first_touch_timestamp)) as user_first_touch_date,
  CASE WHEN r.has_appRemove >= 1 THEN "removed" ELSE "not-removed" END AS status_after_first7days
FROM `firebase-analytics-sample-data.ios_dataset.app_events_*` f
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_pseudo_id, 1 has_appRemove
    FROM `firebase-analytics-sample-data.ios_dataset.app_events_*`
    WHERE DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
      AND DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)) < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 9 DAY)
      AND _TABLE_SUFFIX >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
      AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
      AND platform = "ANDROID"
      AND event_name = "app_remove"
    GROUP BY user_pseudo_id
    ) r on f.user_pseudo_id = r.user_pseudo_id
WHERE
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
  AND DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)) < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 9 DAY)
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
  AND platform = "ANDROID" 
ORDER BY 1,2 ASC
```

Comment: How many rows does this produce? Can you use a limit? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-output#use_a_limit_clause_with_large_sorts

Comment: Hi Elliot, I can unfortunately not apply the LIMIT, because I am using this query to write data to a long-term table (via bigquery task scheduler everyday). I used the partition answer from Mikhail and it did the job :)

Comment: Great! I'm glad that Mikhail's answer worked for you. Note that if you're writing the results to another table, though, the `ORDER BY` is meaningless, since tables don't preserve order; only query results do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply windowing/analytical function instead of join'ing - like in below example (not tested)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  user_pseudo_id,
  event_timestamp, 
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) AS event_timestamp_date,
  event_name,
  user_first_touch_timestamp,
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)) AS user_first_touch_date,
  COUNTIF(event_name = "app_remove") OVER(PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id) > 0 isRemoved
FROM `firebase-analytics-sample-data.ios_dataset.app_events_*` 
WHERE
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
  AND DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)) < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 9 DAY)
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
  AND platform = "ANDROID" 
ORDER BY 1,2 ASC
```